# callback google analytics nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, google-api-nodejs-client

I've made an nodeJS app with express. I am able to retrieve data from google analytics, however I'm not able to show the data on the screen, since the authorization/google analytics api is asynchronous.

Can someone help me with writing a function with callback, which will update a div called '.report' index page and show the JSON inside the div.

**javascripts/googleAuth.js**

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var path = require("path");
var getJWTClient = {
    authorize: function () {
        var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
            'cboboekverkoperdashboardv2@clear-style-185306.iam.gserviceaccount.com',  
            path.join(__dirname, '../.', '/files/KEY.json'), 
            null,
            ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'] //scope
        );
        jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
            console.log('jwtClient.authorize() started');
            if (err) {
                console.log('error in authorization:' + err);
                return;
            } else {
                console.log('authorization success!');
                var analytics = google.analytics('v3');
                return queryData(analytics,jwtClient);
            }
        })
    }
}

function queryData(analytics,jwtClient){
    var VIEW_ID = 'ga:163754738';
    analytics.data.ga.get({
        'auth': jwtClient,
        'ids': VIEW_ID,
        'metrics': 'ga:uniquePageviews',
        'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
        'start-date': '30daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'yesterday',
        'sort': '-ga:uniquePageviews',
        'max-results': 10,

    }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
        // should be able to update the .report on index page with this information.

        return JSON.stringify(response, null, 4);
    });
}
module.exports = getJWTClient;
```

**My app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**index.pug**

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  div(class='report') #{jsonReport}
```

**Routing/index.pug**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var googleAuth = require('../public/javascripts/googleAuth.js');
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Dashboard', jsonReport: googleAuth.authorize() });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: @xavier.seignard Can you help me out?

Comment: @abel can you help me out with updating the pug file?